# Python animation with multiple lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to display a Python 2.7 Matplotlib figure, animated to show 2 lines, looping through 11 files each containing different month data

The line data is held in dataframes called CoinMarketData[i] for frames 1 through 11, in the columns 'Log MC' and 'Log EMC'.

The code I have so far:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,100), ylim=(0,30))
N=11
lines = [plt.plot([], [])[0] for _ in range(N)]

def init():
    for line in lines:
        line.set_data([],[])
    return lines

def animate(i):
    for j,line in enumerate(lines):
        # I think i need to put lists of the X and Y data in here
        lines.set_data(x, y) # set_data only takes 2 arguments...how do I set both y and y2 to the lines?
    return lines

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
           frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)
        
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have 2 lines, don't create 11 of them. Since each line belongs to one column, you can set the data seperately.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N=11

dataframes = [pd.DataFrame({"x":np.sort(np.random.rand(10)*100),
                            "y1":np.random.rand(10)*30,
                            "y2":np.random.rand(10)*30}) for _ in range(N)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0,100), ylim=(0,30))

lines = [plt.plot([], [])[0] for _ in range(2)]

def animate(i):
    lines[0].set_data(dataframes[i]["x"], dataframes[i]["y1"])
    lines[1].set_data(dataframes[i]["x"], dataframes[i]["y2"])
    return lines

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 
           frames=N, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```